# Use socket.io with HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: sockets, ssl, socket.io

I am using self-signed certificated to encrypt traffic data.
My **.crt** and **.key** files are located at **/etc/nginx/ssl/**

(**some_file.key** and **some_file.crt**)

I was using socket.io over http but tried to get it over to https. Here is my actual code:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('../etc/nginx/ssl/some_file.key').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('../etc/nginx/ssl/some_file.crt').toString();

//how can I exclude this? (I have no intermediate, should I?)
var ca = fs.readFileSync('../intermediate.crt').toString();

var app = express.createServer({key:privateKey,cert:certificate,ca:ca });
var io = require('socket.io');

app.listen(3000, function(){
    //wait on 3000
});

app.post('/posts', function(req, res){
    //server communication
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //wait on connections
});
```

Client-side:

```
var socket = io(url + ":3000", { "secure": true, 'connect timeout': 5000 });
```

**Is this the correct way to do it?** I based my https code on examples, so I'm doubting on whether this is well enough (I know it isn't, but should be close). When I run the code, I also get an error `no such file or directory '../etc/nginx/ssl/some_file.key'`...

Comment: why you use ../etc/nginx... path if files are at /etc/nginx...? And you don't need intermediate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it this way, although this is very dependent on express version you are using. This is for version 3.4

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
,fs = require('fs')
,events = require('events');
...
var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/some_file.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/some_file.crt')
};

/*
*Configuration
*
*/
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app), io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var port = 8443;
var ipaddr = '0.0.0.0';

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', port);
    app.set('ipaddr', ipaddr);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    ...
});
```